# rmmod: Resources temporarily unavailable

Tags: c++, linux, bash, fpga

I have a C++ program, a Linux driver and a Bash script. The C++ program will communicate with the FPGA through the driver. To program the FPGA, I need to unload the driver, program FPGA and reload driver afterwards. And those are the tasks in the Bash script.

Basically what I want to achieve is when the C++ program receives a particular command from the client program, it will launch the Bash script to kill the C++ program, unload driver, program FPGA, load back the driver and start again the C++ program. But when I use `system` , `fork` and `execl` to launch the script within the C++ program, the rmmod is not successful with error message "resources temporarily unavailable". Looks like the driver thinks the C++ program is still using it.

But I thought when I use `fork` and `execl`, if I kill the C++ program from other process will free up the driver, no? What should I do to kill the program and unload the driver?

Comment: If the driver is the same before and after reprogramming the FPGA, you don't have to unload the driver. You should only ensure that there are no pending transactions on the bus.

Comment: I assume you are using a PCIe core? Which one do you use?

Comment: I need to unload the driver, if not the driver would crash even I'm pretty sure there is no transaction going on. No, I'm working on Altera Cyclone V so the driver basically is to enable the communication between ARM and FPGA through AXI bus.

Comment: I think it's not necessary to use a bash script. You can use normal read/write operations on sysfs to modify the driver binding `/sys/bus/pci/drivers/<xxx>/unbind`. Your Linux should also handle add and remove action on a device. For example (PCIe) `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/remove`. Removing a device unbinds and unloads it's driver. You can try this by hand as root with tools like echo and cat.